# Interpret deadlock and fix it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, deadlock

I need to understand how this is possible, i.e. I would like to understand mechanics of this.

[image]
[image]

Victim process is a big union-type query involves about 6 tables (Entity Frameworks)

Process on a right is an insert/update batch consisting of multiple statements.

I can't give SQL since they truncated in deadlock event.

I've seen deadlocks involving 2/3 tables and write operations, but I can't interpret this one. What happening? I see index involved, this is valid index - I need it.

I get this deadlock maybe 3 times a week on a system where about 100 such selects per minute and about 1 such insert per second

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process2fdc4e088">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process2fdc4e088" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 28:72057594054049792 (7303a0672d4e)" waittime="713" ownerId="928827354" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2012-06-27T06:32:35.030" XDES="0x9982e3b0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="3" kpid="15300" status="suspended" spid="84" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2012-06-27T06:32:35.137" lastbatchcompleted="2012-06-27T06:32:35.030" clientapp="sss" hostname="aaa" hostpid="4080" loginname="aaa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="928827354" currentdb="28" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x020000009b2fc809e2d580f750aacd7697bcc9fab8b85647">
SELECT 
[UnionAll2].[C3] AS [C1], 
[UnionAll2].[C4] AS [C2], 
[UnionAll2].[C5] AS [C3], 
[UnionAll2].[C6] AS [C4], 
[UnionAll2].[C7] AS [C5], 
[UnionAll2].[C8] AS [C6], 
[UnionAll2].[C9] AS [C7], 
[UnionAll2].[C10] AS [C8], 
[UnionAll2].[C11] AS [C9], 
[UnionAll2].[C12] AS [C10], 
[UnionAll2].[C13] AS [C11], 
[UnionAll2].[C14] AS [C12], 
[UnionAll2].[C15] AS [C13], 
[UnionAll2].[C16] AS [C14], 
[UnionAll2].[C17] AS [C15], 
[UnionAll2].[C18] AS [C16], 
[UnionAll2].[C19] AS [C17], 
[UnionAll2].[C20] AS [C18], 
[UnionAll2].[C21] AS [C19], 
[UnionAll2].[C22] AS [C20], 
[UnionAll2].[C23] AS [C21], 
[UnionAll2].[C24] AS [C22], 
[UnionAll2].[C25] AS [C23], 
[UnionAll2].[C1] AS [C24], 
[UnionAll2].[C26] AS [C25], 
[UnionAll2].[C27] AS [C26], 
[UnionAll2].[C28] AS [C27], 
[UnionAll2].[C29] AS [C28], 
[UnionAll2].[C30] AS [C29], 
[UnionAll2].[C31] AS [C30], 
[UnionAll2].[C32] AS [C31], 
[UnionAll2].[C33] AS [C32], 
[UnionAll2].[C34] AS [C33], 
[UnionAll2].[C35] AS [C34], 
[UnionAll2].     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
SELECT 
[UnionAll2].[C3] AS [C1], 
[UnionAll2].[C4] AS [C2], 
[UnionAll2].[C5] AS [C3], 
[UnionAll2].[C6] AS [C4], 
[UnionAll2].[C7] AS [C5], 
[UnionAll2].[C8] AS [C6], 
[UnionAll2].[C9] AS [C7], 
[UnionAll2].[C10] AS [C8], 
[UnionAll2].[C11] AS [C9], 
[UnionAll2].[C12] AS [C10], 
[UnionAll2].[C13] AS [C11], 
[UnionAll2].[C14] AS [C12], 
[UnionAll2].[C15] AS [C13], 
[UnionAll2].[C16] AS [C14], 
[UnionAll2].[C17] AS [C15], 
[UnionAll2].[C18] AS [C16], 
[UnionAll2].[C19] AS [C17], 
[UnionAll2].[C20] AS [C18], 
[UnionAll2].[C21] AS [C19], 
[UnionAll2].[C22] AS [C20], 
[UnionAll2].[C23] AS [C21], 
[UnionAll2].[C24] AS [C22], 
[UnionAll2].[C25] AS [C23], 
[UnionAll2].[C1] AS [C24], 
[UnionAll2].[C26] AS [C25], 
[UnionAll2].[C27] AS [C26], 
[UnionAll2].[C28] AS [C27], 
[UnionAll2].[C29] AS [C28], 
[UnionAll2].[C30] AS [C29], 
[UnionAll2].[C31] AS [C30], 
[UnionAll2].[C32] AS [C31], 
[UnionAll2].[C33] AS [C32], 
[UnionAll2].[C34] AS [C33], 
[UnionAll2].[C35] AS [C34], 
[UnionAll2]    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="processd5471948" taskpriority="0" logused="1204" waitresource="PAGE: 28:1:102676" waittime="864" ownerId="928827514" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2012-06-27T06:32:35.363" XDES="0x1e0f0d3f0" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="4" kpid="19116" status="suspended" spid="77" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2012-06-27T06:32:35.377" lastbatchcompleted="2012-06-27T06:32:35.377" clientapp="DitatTMS" hostname="sss" hostpid="4080" loginname="sss" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="928827514" currentdb="28" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="50" stmtend="250" sqlhandle="0x020000003859c72d14e4f731cc12f95e6e3ed8b75668b3b9">
update [dbo].[MBLTripStopAttribute]
set [AttributeValue] = @0
where ([TripStopAttributeKey] = @1)     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@0 varchar(max) ,@1 int)update [dbo].[MBLTripStopAttribute]
set [AttributeValue] = @0
where ([TripStopAttributeKey] = @1)
select [RowVersion]
from [dbo].[MBLTripStopAttribute]
where @@ROWCOUNT &gt; 0 and [TripStopAttributeKey] = @1    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594054049792" dbid="28" objectname="DitatApp.dbo.MBLTripDriver" indexname="IX_MBLTripDriver_UpdatedOn_DriverKey" id="lock873ee900" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594054049792">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="processd5471948" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process2fdc4e088" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="102676" dbid="28" objectname="DitatApp.dbo.MBLTripStopAttribute" id="lock92d2c200" mode="SIU" associatedObjectId="72057594055163904">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process2fdc4e088" mode="S"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="processd5471948" mode="IX" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Comment: Is the image truncated?  I see arrows coming in from the side.

Comment: Use the deadlock source XML. The [image is often ambigous](http://rusanu.com/2010/05/12/the-puzzle-of-u-locks-in-deadlock-graphs/)

Comment: @Andomar I broke image in 2 - otherwise it was too small. Visually "merge" top and bottom parts as left and right - middle portion shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like process 84 holds a shared-intent-update pagelock A.  It is waiting for a shared key lock on B.

Process 77 holds an exclusive key lock on B.  It's waiting for an intent exclusive page lock on A.

The next step is retrieving the SQL statements these processes were executing.

Comment: I can post approximate SQL, query for left side will be pretty much spot on, but right-side query will be only to "illustrate" as number of inserts/updates in that transaction vary. Will it help to better diagnose? Like I said XML is of no help - queries large and truncated..

Comment: @katit: We'd need both the queries, and not just the current query, but all queries that are part of that transaction.  If it happens three times a week, you can [Enable the Trace flag 3604 followed by 1204.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Performance+Tuning/tracingdeadlocks/1324/)