# Deadlock while adding a cloned entity in EF Core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

We have run into a very strange deadlock problem with our EF Core project in staging environment/SQL Azure. The same code works all the time without fail locally but when we clone the entity and save it in DB in Azure, it keeps on giving random deadlock errors.

Here's how we get our entity:

```
var companyQuery = this.dbContext.Companies
    ...
    ...  //Removed for brevity
    ...
    .ThenInclude(a => a.User)
    .AsQueryable().AsNoTracking();

var company = await companyQuery.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

//Do some more processing

return company;
```

Once we have got the entity from DB, we clone it using the following code:

```
var clonedCompany = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Company>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(company, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore })); 

//Do data cleansing/clear values and other stuff...

this.dbContext.Companies.Add(company);
await this.dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This code works fine locally with a SQL database. When we move this to Azure staging environment, with DB server set to tier S2 (50 DTU), it keeps on throwing errors. It works sometimes but fails at other times.

Since the code is same, I suspect this has to be related to the infrastructural level changes. Here's how the snapshot of my DTU usage looks in Azure:

[image: Azure Portal Usage stats]
[image: Similar results via query analyzer]

This probably rules out database throughput.

NB: The cloned entity has nested structure with some of leaf level children running up-to 50 in numbers.

The error log we get is only related to 2 specific children (KPI and Periods within the same parent entity). The deadlock occurs between the same or the both the entities at different times.

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="processa04718d088" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="processa04718d088" taskpriority="0" logused="77216" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057594054574080 (f95025ebb6bc)" waittime="2634" ownerId="6886" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-07-24T07:21:40.750" XDES="0xa0478104c0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="35744" status="suspended" spid="126" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-07-24T07:21:40.980" lastbatchcompleted="2017-07-24T07:21:40.950" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.950" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="RD000D3AB1A38A" hostpid="17512" loginname="test_environment" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="6886" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0xce20e7de637aa7a6" queryplanhash="0xa006c48362dbc31a" line="12" stmtstart="22034" stmtend="25988" sqlhandle="0x02000000393ca3073882392dc843159f37107cfbb2db3f160000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@p374 uniqueidentifier,@p375 bit,@p376 uniqueidentifier,@p377 uniqueidentifier,@p378 uniqueidentifier,@p379 nvarchar(4000),@p380 uniqueidentifier,@p381 uniqueidentifier,@p382 bit,@p383 nvarchar(4000),@p384 nvarchar(4000),@p385 uniqueidentifier,@p386 int,@p387 uniqueidentifier,@p388 bit,@p389 nvarchar(4000),@p390 nvarchar(4000),@p391 uniqueidentifier,@p392 int,@p393 uniqueidentifier,@p394 bit,@p395 nvarchar(4000),@p396 nvarchar(4000),@p397 uniqueidentifier,@p398 int,@p399 uniqueidentifier,@p400 bit,@p401 nvarchar(4000),@p402 nvarchar(4000),@p403 uniqueidentifier,@p404 int,@p405 uniqueidentifier,@p406 bit,@p407 nvarchar(4000),@p408 nvarchar(4000),@p409 uniqueidentifier,@p410 int,@p411 uniqueidentifier,@p412 bit,@p413 nvarchar(4000),@p414 nvarchar(4000),@p415 uniqueidentifier,@p416 int,@p417 uniqueidentifier,@p418 bit,@p419 nvarchar(4000),@p420 nvarchar(4000),@p421 uniqueidentifier,@p422 int,@p423 uniqueidentifier,@p424 uniqueidentifier,@p425 nvarchar(4000),@p426 uniqueidentifier,@p427 nvarchar(4000),@p428 uni   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="processa0441304e8" taskpriority="0" logused="78852" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057594054574080 (c2973424f97f)" waittime="2631" ownerId="6883" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-07-24T07:21:40.750" XDES="0xa04d3dc4c0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="100668" status="suspended" spid="125" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-07-24T07:21:40.960" lastbatchcompleted="2017-07-24T07:21:40.947" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.947" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="RD000D3AB1A38A" hostpid="17512" loginname="test_environment" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="6883" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0xce20e7de637aa7a6" queryplanhash="0xa006c48362dbc31a" line="12" stmtstart="22034" stmtend="25988" sqlhandle="0x02000000393ca3073882392dc843159f37107cfbb2db3f160000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@p374 uniqueidentifier,@p375 bit,@p376 uniqueidentifier,@p377 uniqueidentifier,@p378 uniqueidentifier,@p379 nvarchar(4000),@p380 uniqueidentifier,@p381 uniqueidentifier,@p382 bit,@p383 nvarchar(4000),@p384 nvarchar(4000),@p385 uniqueidentifier,@p386 int,@p387 uniqueidentifier,@p388 bit,@p389 nvarchar(4000),@p390 nvarchar(4000),@p391 uniqueidentifier,@p392 int,@p393 uniqueidentifier,@p394 bit,@p395 nvarchar(4000),@p396 nvarchar(4000),@p397 uniqueidentifier,@p398 int,@p399 uniqueidentifier,@p400 bit,@p401 nvarchar(4000),@p402 nvarchar(4000),@p403 uniqueidentifier,@p404 int,@p405 uniqueidentifier,@p406 bit,@p407 nvarchar(4000),@p408 nvarchar(4000),@p409 uniqueidentifier,@p410 int,@p411 uniqueidentifier,@p412 bit,@p413 nvarchar(4000),@p414 nvarchar(4000),@p415 uniqueidentifier,@p416 int,@p417 uniqueidentifier,@p418 bit,@p419 nvarchar(4000),@p420 nvarchar(4000),@p421 uniqueidentifier,@p422 int,@p423 uniqueidentifier,@p424 uniqueidentifier,@p425 nvarchar(4000),@p426 uniqueidentifier,@p427 nvarchar(4000),@p428 uni   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594054574080" dbid="6" objectname="94db1ff7-84a0-4a4f-a49f-31427efbd904.dbo.Periods" indexname="PK_Periods" id="locka04eb42480" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594054574080">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="processa0441304e8" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="processa04718d088" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594054574080" dbid="6" objectname="94db1ff7-84a0-4a4f-a49f-31427efbd904.dbo.Periods" indexname="PK_Periods" id="locka04eb42e80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594054574080">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="processa04718d088" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="processa0441304e8" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

This basically tells me nothing other than the concerned tables and that's its the query generated by Entity Framework. What could be the issue?

TIA

Comment: Have you followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-event-log-azure-sql-database#examples) for checking deadlock? From the `excutionStack`, we could not locate the actual SQL statement. Here are some  similar issues, you could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228043/interpret-deadlock-and-fix-it) and [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/sql-server-deadlocks-by-example/) for a better understanding of deadlock.